# How to check if []byte is all zeros in go

Tags: go, slice

Is there a way to check if a byte slice is empty or 0 without checking each element or using reflect?

```
theByteVar := make([]byte, 128)

if "theByteVar is empty or zeroes" {
   doSomething()
}
```

One solution which seems weird that I found was to keep an empty byte array for comparison.

```
theByteVar := make([]byte, 128)
emptyByteVar := make([]byte, 128)

// fill with anything
theByteVar[1] = 2

if reflect.DeepEqual(theByteVar,empty) == false {
   doSomething(theByteVar)
}
```

For sure there must be a better/quicker solution.

Thanks

UPDATE did some comparison for 1000 loops and the reflect way is the worst by far...

```
Equal Loops: 1000 in true in 19.197µs
Contains Loops: 1000 in true in 34.507µs
AllZero Loops: 1000 in true in 117.275µs
Reflect Loops: 1000 in true in 14.616277ms
```

Comment: Initially, theByteVar has len() of 0 and cap() of 128. Len() of 0 means it is empty. If not empty, you can then use a for/range to test for non-zero and break on first occurrence when it is not empty.

Comment: But, you seem to be confused about slices and arrays. Make sure to understand the difference. For an array you will need to iterate over all elements to test for non-zero.

Comment: It seems len returns 128 as well so I cannot check for empty. https://play.golang.org/p/plx-vt0XjC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can possibly use bytes.Equal or bytes.Contains to compare with a zero initialized byte slice, see https://play.golang.org/p/mvUXaTwKjP, I haven't checked for performance, but hopefully it's been optimized. You might want to try out other solutions and compare the performance numbers, if needed.

Answer (score 7):

Comparing it with another slice containing only zeros, that requires reading (and comparing) 2 slices.

Using a single for loop will be more efficient here:

```
for _, v := range theByteVar {
    if v != 0 {
        doSomething(theByteVar)
        break
    }
}
```

If you do need to use it in multiple places, wrap it in a utility function:

```
func allZero(s []byte) bool {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v != 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

And then using it:

```
if !allZero(theByteVar) {
    doSomething(theByteVar)
}
```

Comment: One advantage to this is that if done properly, you'll take advantage of CPU L1 cache optimizations, such as Intel's static read prediction. This is why the Go language has you just iterate over items in a collection instead of using some fancy built-in abstracted extension. As long as you keep your structs aligned, and you are using L1 smartly that is.  For example, if swapping bytes often, you may want to store the bits in int64 instead: so you would have less L1 cache invalidation.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution borrows an idea from C. It could be achieved by using the `unsafe` package in Go.

The idea is simple, instead of checking each byte from []byte, we can check the value of `byte[i:i+8]`, which is a `uint64` value, in each steps. By doing this we can check 8 bytes instead of checking only one byte in each iteration.

Below codes are not best practice but only show the idea.

```golang
func IsAllBytesZero(data []byte) bool {
    n := len(data)

    // Round n down to the nearest multiple of 8
    // by clearing the last 3 bits.
    nlen8 := n & ^0b111
    i := 0

    for ; i < nlen8; i += 8 {
        b := *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[i]))
        if b != 0 {
            return false
        }
    }

    for ; i < n; i++ {
        if data[i] != 0 {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

## Benchmark

### Testcases:

Only test for worst cases (all elements are zero)

### Methods:

- IsAllBytesZero: `unsafe` package solution
- NaiveCheckAllBytesAreZero: a loop to iterate the whole byte array and check it.
- CompareAllBytesWithFixedEmptyArray: using `bytes.Compare` solution with pre-allocated fixed size empty byte array.
- CompareAllBytesWithDynamicEmptyArray: using `bytes.Compare` solution without pre-allocated fixed size empty byte array.

### Results

```
BenchmarkIsAllBytesZero10-8                                 254072224            4.68 ns/op
BenchmarkIsAllBytesZero100-8                                132266841            9.09 ns/op
BenchmarkIsAllBytesZero1000-8                               19989015            55.6 ns/op
BenchmarkIsAllBytesZero10000-8                               2344436           507 ns/op
BenchmarkIsAllBytesZero100000-8                              1727826           679 ns/op
BenchmarkNaiveCheckAllBytesAreZero10-8                      234153582            5.15 ns/op
BenchmarkNaiveCheckAllBytesAreZero100-8                     30038720            38.2 ns/op
BenchmarkNaiveCheckAllBytesAreZero1000-8                     4300405           291 ns/op
BenchmarkNaiveCheckAllBytesAreZero10000-8                     407547          2666 ns/op
BenchmarkNaiveCheckAllBytesAreZero100000-8                     43382         27265 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithFixedEmptyArray10-8             415171356            2.71 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithFixedEmptyArray100-8            218871330            5.51 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithFixedEmptyArray1000-8           56569351            21.0 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithFixedEmptyArray10000-8           6592575           177 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithFixedEmptyArray100000-8           567784          2104 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithDynamicEmptyArray10-8           64215448            19.8 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithDynamicEmptyArray100-8          32875428            35.4 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithDynamicEmptyArray1000-8          8580890           140 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithDynamicEmptyArray10000-8         1277070           938 ns/op
BenchmarkCompareAllBytesWithDynamicEmptyArray100000-8         121256         10355 ns/op
```

## Summary

Assumed that we're talking about the condition in sparse zero byte array. According to the benchmark, if performance is an issue, the naive check solution would be a bad idea. And, if you don't want to use `unsafe` package in your project, then consider using `bytes.Compare` solution with pre-allocated empty array as an alternative.

An interesting point could be pointed out is that the performance comes from `unsafe` package varies a lot, but it basically outperform all other solution mentioned above. I think it was relevant to the CPU cache mechanism.

Comment: This line seems to be mistyped, `i` does not need to be multiplied by 8: `b := *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0])) + 8*uintptr(i)))`. Just `*(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[i]))` should work.

Comment: @Laurence I think you are right. I edited their answer to prevent future readers from running into issues in case they don't see your comment (as I didn't at first).

Comment: Another issue is that using `0xFFFFFFF8` as the bitmask means this will fail on 64-bit machines if the length of the buffer is greater than `0xFFFFFFFF`. Fixed by changing it to `^0b111`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better (faster) if `binary or` is used instead of `if condition` inside loop:

```
func isZero(bytes []byte) bool {
    b := byte(0)
    for _, s := range bytes {
        b |= s
    }
    return b == 0
}
```

One can optimize this even more by using idea with `uint64` mentioned in previous answers